# Problem override handleMethodArgumentNotValid from ResponseEntityExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to override the handleMethodArgumentNotValid method but without success.

The error I'm getting is: "the method handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException, HttpHeaders, HttpStatus, WebRequest) of type CustomResponseEntityExceptionHandler must override or implement a supertype but I don't know why I'm not doing it already.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class CustomResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
    var exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse(new Date(), ex.getMessage(), request.getDescription(false));

    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}

@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>("test", HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
}

@ExceptionHandler(UserNotFoundException.class)
public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleUserNotFoundExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
    var exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse(new Date(), ex.getMessage(), request.getDescription(false));

    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

}

I'm following this tutorial if it's any help: https://www.baeldung.com/global-error-handler-in-a-spring-rest-api

Comment: Why do you add `@RestController`? Check tutorial more carefully.
Here code [link](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-security-modules/spring-security-web-rest/src/main/java/com/baeldung/errorhandling/CustomRestExceptionHandler.java#L28)

Comment: Because I return HTTP responses so I thought that was appropriate. Anyways that's not the problem and deleting it changes nothing, I still get the exact same error.

Comment: Check overridden method signature and imports of variable

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are not using other parameters try this

```
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>("test", HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
}
```